# jquery slide animation automated

Tags: jquery, user-interface, slider

When you click the slider and drag it halfway or more, the image changes. The image will only change when the mouse click has been released. Is there anyway to make the change take place without the user having to unclick the mouse?

Please see the codepen file: http://codepen.io/seantreanor/pen/zGapYW

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        step: 1,
        change: function(event, ui){
            if(ui.value <=49){
                $('#image').attr('src','http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg');
            } else if(ui.value >=50) {
                $('#image').attr('src','http://www.menucool.com/slider/jsImgSlider/images/image-slider-2.jpg');
            };
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `slide` instead of `change`. [API Docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide)

Comment: You are the best! Since you have been able to help me with this, i was wondering would you be able to help me with this one.

Comment: I want to have a div that has a title and some description text. I want the text and title to change when each new image appears? Any advice? :)

Comment: [This](http://plnkr.co/edit/djcosOH36INVihiglewS?p=preview) i believe is what you're asking for in terms of functionality. Now i'm supposed to enforce asking this as a seperate question, but whatever... Also please remember to accept my post as the answer. Upvote would be nice too.

Comment: I actually just updated my answer to help with scalability. If you have a lot of images it will probably help to store all of their info in a list of dictionaries.